# How do i save the updates i made to a group from my df into the df?

Tags: python, pandas

i have a df similar to this:

| id | name | treat | snack | year |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ac2 | canela | brownie |  |  |
| bd4 | cheerio |  | chips | 1990 |
| ac2 | canela |  | pretzel |  |
| bd4 | cheerio | cookie |  |  |
| ac2 | canela |  |  | 2004 |

i want my resulting table to look like this:

| id | name | treat | snack | year |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ac2 | canela | brownie | pretzel | 2004 |
| bd4 | cheerio | cookie | chips | 1990 |

what i have done so far is this:

```py
id_ls = [ac2, bd4 ...]
gb_df = df.groupby('id')
gb_df.apply(lambda x:x) # to get it as a df again - not sure if this a bad idea

for i in id_ls:
   gb_df.get_group(i).ffill().bfill()
```

so this part `gb_df.get_group(i).ffill().bfill()` when done on a single id work the way i want it too but it does not save this updated fill into the df. how do i do this?

thanks in advance!!

Comment: `df.groupby('id', as_index=False).first()`

Answer (score 0):

If your blank cells are empty strings:

```
>>> df.replace("",None).groupby("id").first()
```